# How to combine a List<decimal> with a specific object List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, arraylist

I have a class

```
public class Market
{
    public List<Employee> MyEmployees { get; set; }

    public List<decimal> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

and the employee class

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to combine the two lists but the problem is i try Zip(Linq) but return an anonymous object and I must assign it in a var variable.
I want to return a specific object that I can assign to

```
List<MyObject> = bla bla..combine my two lists.
```

i want to have a new list which contains Id ,Name ,Birthday , a payment(decimal) in each record

Comment: Please show what you have done and elaborate on what _exactly_ you want to achieve... If you want to use `MyObject` instead an anonymous type, _what exactly_ keeps you from doing so?

Comment: i want to have a new list which contains Id ,Name ,Birthday , a payment(decimal) in each record

Comment: @dimmits make sure to include the info about MyObject in the question

Comment: So I guess (but actually you should show, because you're the only one to know exactly) you are currently doing something like `MyEmployees.Zip(Payments, (e, p) => new {Id = e.Id, Name = e.Name, Birthday = e.Birthday, Payment = p});`, but you want to use `MyObject` instead of the anonymous type? Then simply declare `MyObject` type accordingly and change the lambda to use it.

Comment: @dimmits I think there are some issues with your structure. You'd expect a payment not to be a singular decimal, you'd normally have it linked to an employee in particular. So it'd be a Payment object with two attributes, paymentValue and employeeID. Then you can join the two lists on the employeeID. You'd likely have a date associated with a payment as well. Just bare this in mind for future processing.

Comment: Please provide your actual query. It´s really hard to guess which anonymous objects you´re talking about - even with René´s guesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we should implement `MyObject`, i.e.

> specific object that I can assign to `List<MyObject>`

Let `MyObject` be something like this:

```
public class MyObject {
  public MyObject(Employee employee, decimal payment) {
    if (null == employee) 
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));

    Employee = employee;
    Payment = payment;
  }

  public Employee Employee {get;}
  public Decimal Payment {get;}

  public int Id => Employee.Id;
  public string Name => Employee.Name
  public DateTime Birthday => Employee.Birthday
}
```

Then you can use simple *Linq*, `Zip` for the query:

```
Market market = ...

List<MyObject> result = market
  .MyEmployees
  .Zip(market.Payments, (employee, payment) => new MyObject(employee, payment))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: it run correctly and thank you very much! but if i dont want to use constructor in MyObject Class how can modify the zip??

Comment: @dimmits: it depends on what is `MyObject` implementation. If you remove `Employee employee, decimal payment` from the constructor, but add `set;` to `public Employee Employee` and `public Decimal Payment` you can put `.Zip(market.Payments, (employee, payment) => new MyObject){Employee = employee, Payment = payment})`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use an anonymous object then declare that object class (Lets call it `PaidEmployee`, add `Employee` and `decimal` Instance variables, and populate each object with a `foreach`

In your `PaidEmployee` class you will probably want either parameters or getters and setters to assign these values

Some other options would be to edit the `Employee` class to add the payment, or maybe an array/dictionary with the values